# Can we construct a counterexample that satifies the conditions?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, pointwise-convergence, almost-everywhere

Let $(X,\mathscr{A},\mu)$ be a measure space. The **Riesz Theorem** in *real analysis* shows that, for $A\in\mathscr{A}$, functions $f,f_{n}:A\to\mathbb{R}$ are $\mu$-measurable, if sequence $\{f_n\}$ is $\mu$-convergent to $f$, then there exists a subsequence $\displaystyle{\{f_{n_{k}}\}}$ of $\{f_n\}$ such that $f_{n_{k}}$ convergent to $f$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

I know the condition "$\mu$-almost everywhere convergence" is necessary, but I wonder if there is a counterexample without this condition. That is to say, are there such functions $f$ and $f_n$ that satify $f_n$ is $\mu$-convergent to $f$, but **do not** exist any subsequences $\{f_{n_{k}}\}$ pointwisely convergent to $f$ in $A$.

Comment: 'I know the condition "μ-almost everywhere convergence" is necessary, but I wonder if there is a counterexample without this condition.': ??? If there's no counterexample without that condition then it's _not_ necessary! (You say you "know" it's necessary - how do you know that?)

Comment: What does $\mu$-convergence mean?

Comment: Because the condiction "$\mu$-almost everywhere" is in the theorem and the theorem is true, so I think the condiction is necessary, but I cannot figure out a counterexample without this condiction.@DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: And "$\mu$-convergence" means that for all $\delta>0$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu(\{|f_n-f|>\delta\})=0$, then we call $f_n$ is $\mu$-convergent to $f$.@DavidC.Ullrich

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly: "$\mu$-convergence" is what's known perhaps more commonly as convergence in measure; you remind us that $\mu$-convergence implies convergence of a subsequence almost everywhere, and wonder whether there's an example showing that it does not imply that some subsequence converges at every point.

The simplest answer is that there must be such an example, since $\mu$-convergence is not affected by sets of measure zero. For example, say $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure. Say $(a_n)$ is a sequence of scalars with no convergent subsequence, and let $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases}0,&(x\ne0),\\a_n,&(x=0).\end{cases}$$Then $f_n$ certainly tends to zero in measure, but no subsequence converges at the origin.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have been thinking about whether I can construct a series of set $A_n$ with convergent measure, and let $f_n$ be the characteristic function of $A_n$ but I failed. Your example is great! This is my first time to ask questions on Stackexchange and I really appreciate your answer!